# how to fetch and store last two months balance transactions from stripe Api

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I am trying to fetch last 2 months transaction lists which has more than 2000 records from stripe API.

I used following code which only fetch 3 days records.

```
    $balance = $this->stripelib->getBalanceTransaction()->all(
        array(
                'limit'   => 100,
                'created' => array(
                    'gte' => strtotime('-2 month'), 
                    'lte' => strtotime('1 day') 
                )
            )
        );


    foreach ($balance->data as $bl){}
    $this->addStripeRecord($balance->data);

    while ($balance->has_more){

        $balance = $this->stripelib->getBalanceTransaction()->all(
        array(
            "limit" => 100,
            "created" => array(
                "gte" => strtotime('-2 month'),
                'lte' => strtotime('1 day')
                ), 
            "starting_after" => $bl->id)
        );

        foreach ($balance->data as $bl){}
```

please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using Stripe's official PHP library and its support for auto-pagination. [0]

```
$transactions = \Stripe\BalanceTransaction::all([
  "created" => [
    "gte" => strtotime('-2 month'),
    "lte" => strtotime('1 day')
  ]
]);
foreach ($transactions->autoPagingIterator() as $transaction) {
  // Do something with $transaction
  print_r($transaction->id . " : " . date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $transaction->created) . "\n");
}
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=php

Comment: thanks karllekko...Its fetching records but its not insertind all data to database

Comment: I think you'd need to open a separate question with the contents of your `addStripeRecord` function then, that seems unrelated to calling the Stripe API itself.